# Is there a framework like ExtJS 4 for "normal" websites?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I like the JavaScript only approach of ExtJS4, which allows me to create and manipulate RIA-web-apps without touching any CSS/HTML, also MVC keeps anything in order.

Is there anything like this for "normal" websites?

I looked at stuff like ember.js, qooxdoo, jquery, batman.js, kickstrap, etc. but all seem like a big blob of HTML/CSS/JS, so they will probably all start to fail when the website gets a certain complexity.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "normal" websites?

Comment: With ExtJS I'm creating RIA application, which use the "browser" as platform, they're like desktop apps, but running in the browser. Facebook, Google, eBay, BBC etc. are not like this but more like "traditional" websites

Answer (score 1):

It may interest you:
[dojotoolkit.org](http://dojotoolkit.org)

What do you mean by "normal" websites exactly?

Comment: Something like this website (stackoverflow). ExtJS is more suited for desktop like RIA apps.

Comment: Ok. So DOjo will be for you more like ExtJS. Websites are always just html/css/js. To make it easier frameworks have template systems.. Maybe you will like Twitter Boostrap or Sceleton? 

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
http://www.getskeleton.com/